# How to get an array with elements that are taken in order from other arrays?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, mapping

I need from this array:

```
const initArray = [
  {
    '18888': [
      {
        unitId: 1,
        venueId: 18888,
      },
      {
        unitId: 2,
        venueId: 18888,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    '19999': [
      {
        unitId: 3,
        venueId: 19999,
      },
      {
        unitId: 4,
        venueId: 19999,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

get something like this:

```
const resultArray1 = [
  {
    unitId: 1,
    venueId: 18888,
  },
  {
    unitId: 3,
    venueId: 19999,
  },
];

const resultArray2 = [
  {
    unitId: 2,
    venueId: 18888,
  },
  {
    unitId: 4,
    venueId: 19999,
  },
];
```

So I need to take first element from '18888' array and first element from '19999' array. Then on next iteration I need take second element form '18888' and second element from '19999'.

I tried to do like this:

```
{unitsPerDay.map((dayUnits: any, index: any) => {
        const units: any = Object.values(dayUnits)[0];

        const getArrayOfUnitsFilteredByVenueId = (ids: any[], units: any) => {
          const res = [];
          const arr = ids.reduce((acc, item) => {
            const arrOfUnits = units.filter((unit: any) => {
              return unit.venueId === item;
            });
            return [...acc, {[item]: arrOfUnits}];
          }, []);

          for (const value of arr) {
            const qwe: any = Object.values(value)[0];
            res.push(qwe[0]);
          }

          return res;
        };

        const result1 = getArrayOfUnitsFilteredByVenueId(allVenueIds, units);
        const result = result1.filter((element) => element !== undefined)
        

        return (....
```

but it does not work, because of qwe[0]...
I guess there is another way to get needed result. Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const map = {};
initArray.forEach((obj) =>
  Object.values(obj)[0].forEach((item, index) => {
    if (!map[index]) map[index] = [];
    map[index].push(item);
  }),
);
```

to map the array based on their index